# In WPF, Drag from one window and drop on another window's context menu alert dialog gets open. This alert dialog gets hang until we move cursor

Tags: c#, wpf

In my wpf application, i try to drag the textblock from one window say (call screen) and drop it on another window say (contact window). now drop the text block on contact window's datagrid's context menu which gets opwn when drag enter event fires and as soon as the drop event fires on context menu then alert dialog (that is show dialog window with ok and cancel buttn) will gets open. This alert dialog gets hang means i can't be able tap on ok button of this alert dialog until i move my cursor around ok button.

Help is highly appreciated..!

Comment: You should post minimal code, which reproduces this behavior.

Comment: The window from where drag the object:                                                                                                                      OnMouseMove()

Comment: The window from where drag the object:                                                                                                                      OnMouseMove() { if(_isMouseDown) { DragDrop.DoDragDrop(parent, draggedObject, DragDropEffects.All); }}                                                                                                                         Drop event on other window : OnDrop() { show alert dialog.. }